# Unable to read data into SQL Server 2005 from an XML file

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I am trying to use the following script to read data from an XML file and insert it into a table called `TermsTree` on SQL Server 2005.

```
INSERT INTO TermsTree (TermID,ParentID,Name)

SELECT X.TermsTree.query('TermID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('ParentID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
FROM (

SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'C:\Users\MehtabM\Desktop\GetAllTermTree.xml',
    SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
    ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('ArrayOfTerm_Child/Term_Child') AS X(TermsTree);
```

A sample of the XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfTerm_Child xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Term_Child>
        <TermID>2021</TermID>
        <Name>A. Geographic locations</Name>
        <ParentID>0</ParentID>
    </Term_Child>
    <Term_Child>
        <TermID>3602</TermID>
        <Name>Oceania</Name>
        <ParentID>2021</ParentID>
    </Term_Child>
    <Term_Child>
        <TermID>3604</TermID>
        <Name>Australasia</Name>
        <ParentID>3602</ParentID>
    </Term_Child>
    </Term_Child>
</ArrayOfTerm_Child>
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? If so, what?

Comment: There is no error message. But 0 rows are affected when i run the sql script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18f84/15

```
declare @xml xml 
select @xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ArrayOfTerm_Child xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <Term_Child>
<TermID>2021</TermID>
<Name>A. Geographic locations</Name>
<ParentID>0</ParentID>
 </Term_Child>
<Term_Child>
<TermID>3602</TermID>
<Name>Oceania</Name>
<ParentID>2021</ParentID>
 </Term_Child>
 <Term_Child>
<TermID>3604</TermID>
<Name>Australasia</Name>
<ParentID>3602</ParentID>
 </Term_Child>
 </ArrayOfTerm_Child>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/')
SELECT X.TermsTree.query('TermID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('ParentID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfTerm_Child/Term_Child') X(TermsTree)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Can I ask how can we edit this select statement to read from an external xml file

Comment: @user2054857 Load it like in [this answer]. Load the file to a XML variable and then query the variable.

Comment: There is no need to use `query` here. Have a look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18f84/24).

Comment: @user2054857 `select @xml=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\data.xml' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA)`

Comment: Can I also ask when I try to use this script declare @xml xml 

select @xml=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\MehtabM\Desktop\GetAllTermTree.xml' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA)
INSERT INTO TermsTree (TermID,ParentID,Name)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/')
SELECT X.TermsTree.query('TermID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('ParentID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.TermsTree.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfTerm_Child/Term_Child') X(TermsTree) I get Incorrect syntax near ';' msg